# Heroku django app createsuperuser

Tags: django, heroku, django-manage.py

I deployed my django app and when I tried

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

I got a timeout awaiting process error. Superuser is not created for the system yet, though i did syncdb by using:

```
heroku run:detached python manage.py createsuperuser
```

But this does not prompt me for the superuser.

Port 5000 is not blocked in my system. How do I make heroku run work (or) how do I create the super user?

Comment: Check your logs `heroku logs` , you may have problems with your requirements.txt

Comment: Also, the syntax to create a super user is: `createsuperuser` without spaces

Comment: @fasouto: I dont have a problem with the requirements.txt. The app is working and I also did syncdb. Only problem is i cannot create a superuser.

Comment: This really looks as though you can't connect, as you seem to be doing the right thing. Can you run `heroku logs`?

Answer (score 88):

do not detach the heroku shell:

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

worked for me

Comment: Be sure to migrate the DB with `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, this is only required if the DB was not migrated prior to calling the `createsuperuser` command.

Answer (score 7):

after wasting entire day i got the answer

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

doesn't run on institute or office lan to run this you must remove system proxy as well

```
 unset http_proxy
`unset https_proxy`
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
```

And then create your superuser from there.  Good luck!

Comment: Try `heroku run bash` and then do a `python manage.py shell`.

Comment: anything with heroku run gives a timeout

Answer (score 1):

More info please.
What DB are you using?
Have you set your local_settings.py?
Are you using Debian?

I use Postgres on Debian so I had to both `apt-get install python-psycopg2` (otherwise you can't use postgres) and `pip install --user psycopg2` (otherwise `pip freeze` misses Postgres), then manually create a user and db. Replace USER with the username from your local_settings.py

```
sudo su - postgres
createuser USER -dPRs
createdb --owner USER  db.db
```