# Can I access Django Admin Site using deployed URL?

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I just deploy my first Django Rest Framework into Heroku. Site URL is `https://mysite.herokuapp.com/`

I already can access admin site using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` through created superuser account.

**But How I am gonna access the admin site using the deployed url?.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents in the databases are not identically the same if you have not synced those databases yet. You might find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081556/heroku-django-app-createsuperuser) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just Visit

```
https://mysite.herokuapp.com/admin/
```

Dont need to do anything.